# Flask blueprint issue with url_for

Tags: flask, blueprint

I work with blueprint in Flask, and my blueprint is initialized like this:

```
my_blueprint= Blueprint('my_blueprint', __name__,
    template_folder='templates',
    static_folder='static')
```

I want to display pictures in my HTML template using `<img src="{{ picture.uri }}" alt="...">` where picture.uri is the path to the picture. I built this path using `os.path.join('/uploads/', f_name])` where f_name is the filename of the picture.

My directory is built this way:

```
app
--templates
--static
--uploads
--__init__.py
```

I don't understand how I can render my picture in the HTML template. What I need to put into the 'src' field of my img tag?

Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can load static file using

```
{{ url_for('static', filename='path/to/file.jpg') }}
```

Will load file from `PROJECT_ROOT/static/path/to/file.jpg`

Keep in mind that this is for development use only, you have to resolve assets from webserver on production.

Comment: Yes I understand with static folder, but my pictures are under uploads (or assets). How can I pass to the template the correct URL using blueprint? What is the best practice to go on production with Flask and assets using blueprint? Thanks for your help.